# DialogFlow WelcomeDefaultIntent

Tags: dialogflow-es

The DialogFlow documentation writes that the base WelcomeDefaultIntent is triggered either by matching training phrases or every time the user starts a dialogue. But this is not true. If the user's phrases match one of the training phrases of another intent, this intent is triggered, instead of a WelcomeIntent. As a result, the user does not understand that he is communicating with the bot and the quality of service fall down. Please, give a hint, how to make the DefaultWelcomeIntent always works first when the user starts a dialogue, no matter what he wrote. I hope on you

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or an example of you chat and the setup of your welcome intent in Dialogflow?

Comment: yes, sure 
1[https://paste.pics/ef4c3ed428c5719bd732d6ad70d224d0]       
2 [https://paste.pics/56111366b4369d15d70623819606e6fa]
3 [https://paste.pics/add52dd2e7177670881cf76c497a062a]
4 [https://paste.pics/3b4494e90356d338137426d9492be5d9]

Comment: Just because the Welcome intent does not always work, but only after the words "hello" and kind like this,, then I trying to block the rest of the intents with the welocme intent and the fallback intent, so that if the bot intervenes in the middle of the conversation, it does not respond to matches
Bot must say Hello and introduce himself, or say that he didn't understand question, and asked to formulate a question in a form understandable to the bot

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected behavior. As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-default#welcome) mentions:

> The default welcome intent is matched in one of two ways:
>
> - One of its training phrases are matched, which are pre-populated with
>   common greetings, like "hello".
> - This intent has a welcome event
>   attached to it, which is triggered when the end-user begins a
>   conversation with your agent via a supported integration.

However, it doesn't specify that no other intents can be matched at the beginning of a conversation. At the end of the day, the default welcome intent is just another intent that is automatically created alongside the agent, and pre-populated with training phrases. Intents will always "compete" with each other's matching phrases, so the best intent gets selected according to the user input, regardless of whether the intent is the welcome default intent or not.

From a natural conversational point of view, it doesn't makes much sense to "force" the welcome intent to always be triggered at the beginning of a conversation, regardless of the user input. An example could be:

> - User: What time is it?
> - Bot: It's 1:55 pm PT.

And you would be forcing this into something like:

> - User: What time is it?
> - Bot: Hey, my name is Bot, how can I help you?
> - User: What time is it?
> - Bot: It's 1:55 pm PT.

Adding an extra interaction for the user.

However, if you do want to force your welcome intent at the start of a conversation, or your use case requires to, you could try with:

- [Dialogflow Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview), or.
- Using the [Detect Intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/api-overview#detect-intent) API method, which can receive a [EventInput](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#eventinput) object that allow for matching intents by event name instead of the natural language input. Hence, you could use this to match the intent attached to the Welcome event, regardless of the user input.