# How do I have my Dialogflow ES bot initiate the welcome intent on any user input, not just greetings?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm trying to build a close-ended chatbot (for whatsapp) that provides customers with a menu of options at the initiation of conversation. The default welcome intent initiates upon receipt of a greeting as defined in training phrases and that's fine, but I'd like the bot to reply with the menu as long as these two conditions exist:

1. It's a "new conversation" and
2. any input is received from the customer, not just a greeting.

I tried to work with the Default Fallback Intent to handle this and I'm just not having any luck with it.

Can someone please suggest a solution that will allow the bot to respond at the start of conversation to any user input, not necessarily just a greeting as defined in the Default Welcome Intent?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. **EventInput with [detectIntent API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent)**: Use the Detect Intent API, which accepts an [EventInput](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#eventinput) object with `WELCOME` event.
2. **[Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview)**: From my own experience, I temporarily configured both the Default Welcome Intent and the Default Fallback Intent to have the same response, adding a context (e.g., "`start_conversation`") to indicate the beginning of the conversation. Other intents were then designed to respond only after a greeting. The context of the intents should be designed to return to `start_conservation`.
   [image]

Related questions
[DialogFlow WelcomeDefaultIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014499)

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: @starball I write my answer first in Korean, my native language. Then, the answer is translated through translate AI.

Comment: 1) what is "translate AI"? Please give a link to the tool's webpage. 2) see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424036/11107541

Comment: @starball [Papago](https://papago.naver.com/) is used as the main, and ,[Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) , Google Translate is used as a sub.

Comment: I didn't know there was a guide to AI translation. I will check the link you attached.